# How to select a list item in perl

Tags: perl, listview, listitem

I have used the bellow code for selecting a row in a list on a windows.

```
@edit = FindWindowLike( $_, undef, "^SysListView32");
if( !@edit )
{
     die "Cannot find window handle for Edit control\n";
}
else
{
  printf( "Edit window handle is %x\n", $edit[ 0 ] );
}   
SelListViewItemText( $edit[ 0 ], "Fax",1);
```

It is producing the output as bellow:
[image: Present output]

And i want my output to be like:
[image: Required Output]

Please help me saying what are all the changes I have to do in my code to get the output like second screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above mentioned code its selecting so the item has gray background. I it has to be blue it should be active (focused) so to do that :
Add this:

```
SetFocus($edit[ 0 ]);
```

before this:

```
SelListViewItemText( $edit[ 0 ], "Fax",1);
```

Comment: I don't want the window to be active. As my script should run while the user session is locked. @user3274006

Comment: In locked session mode one can't focus make an window active. The change u need is only possible in active session according to me.